# Slow first Realm Init on Cold Launch

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have this setup for initializing realm in my app (there are a bunch of time stamps because I’m going crazy trying to debug why it's so slow).
I now notice that the only hang in this bit of code is when actually initializing Realm.
Between `print("Calling realm init at: \(Date())")` and `print("Realm finished initializing at: \(Date())")` it can take up to 30 seconds.

One thing to note is that this issue only affects cold launches. Warm launches work great. Is there anything i am doing wrong in my realm initialization?

```swift
public extension DispatchQueue {

    static let realmThread = DispatchQueue(
        label: "realmThread",
        qos: .background)
    
}
```

```swift
let config = user.configuration(partitionValue: "\(user.id)")
```

```swift
DispatchQueue.realmThread.async {
    do {
        try autoreleasepool {
            print("Calling realm init at: \(Date())") // Up to 30 seconds between here
            let realm = try Realm(configuration: config, queue: DispatchQueue.realmThread)
            print("Realm finished initializing at: \(Date())") // and here
            self.realm = realm
            print("Realm set into local property at: \(Date())")
            completionHandler(true, nil)
            print("Completion handler fired at: \(Date())")
        }

    } catch(let error) {
        print(error)
        print()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing that? Is there a specific use case for that implementation? You don't need DispatchQueue for what's presented in the code nor the autorelease pool <- that's for when you've got long-winded writes. The Dispatch queue is only for when you need to update the UI within an asynchronous call. Please take a look at [Open a Realm](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/quick-start-with-sync/#open-a-realm) to use a starting template. If there's more to it, update your question and code and we'll take a look. Oh, and you should be using `Realm.asyncOpen(` to open a sync'd realm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqos/qosclass/background), `.background` has the lowest priority which could be one of the reasons why it's taking so long to set it up.

Try to perform it on a queue with `.userInitiated` or `.userInteractive` quality of service and see whether it behaves differently.